# Анимация и потоки android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, анимация

Моя программа инициализирует bluetooth устройство по нажатии кнопки. Одновременно с этим должна запуститься анимация этой кнопки - rotate

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.toggleGreenLed:
            try {
                int value = 0;

                value = (greenButton.isChecked() ? 1 : 0) + 130;
                OutputStream outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

                outStream.write(value);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        case R.id.connect:
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { //ui поток в главном потоке
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    button.startAnimation(animation);

                }
            });
            tryConnectToWatch(); //инициализация bluetooth модуля (не смартфона)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Подождите...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            break;
    }
}
```

Но по задумке не происходит. Сначала инициализируется(секунд 5), а потом после окончания инициализации запускается анимация.

Почему? Ведь отдельный поток.

Comment: В Android есть специальные классы для работы с многопоточностью. Посмотрите на `Handler` `AsyncTask`, они лучше подойдут, нежели простой(сырой) поток или `runOnUiThread` .

По хорошему, вам по нажатию кнопки просто нужно создавать экземпляр `AsyncTask` и в нем обрабатывать все ваши действия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы инициализируете bluetooth в UI потоке это значит что анимация и операция инциализации выполнятся поочередно. Судя и вашего кода сначала отработает tryConnectToWatch метод, а потом анимация. Если вы хотите что бы эти две операции отработали одновременно Попробуйте следующий код:

```
button.startAnimation(animation);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tryConnectToWatch();
        }
    }).start();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Подождите...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Если инициализация блютуз соединения не требует работы в UI потоке, этот код должен работать.

Comment: Спасибо, как я сам не додумался... Возьму на заметку!

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том что вы запускаете анимацию не в отдельном потоке. Вы запускаете её в том же потоке где и запускаете ваш блютус. Почему так ? Потому что в главном потоке всё работает по принципу эвент-луп, вы просто поставили задачу анимации в очередь эвентлупа, однако текущая задача выполняется поэтому ваша задача которую вы положили в эвентлуп ждёт заверешения текущей задачи.

По идеи включение блютус устройства как раз вам нужно делать в отдельном потоке, при том скорее всего отличном от ui потока, т.е. сделать через new Thread(new Runnable()).

Answer (score 2):

Если я не ошибаюсь, создавать поток надо так: сначала надо создать экземпляр класса `Runnable`:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // код
        }
};
```

Затем создать объект класса `Thread` и в его конструктор передать наш `runnable` и вызвать на объекте метод `.start()`:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start()'
```

Можно немножко сократить код:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         //код
      });
    } 
}).start();
```

Также можно использовать `AsynkTask`:

```
class MyThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      // выполнится до запуска doInBackground
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // наш код в потоке
      return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      // выполнится после doInBackground
    }
}
```

Вызов:

```
MyThread m = new MyThread();
m.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно делать ваш коннект к браслету в отдельном потоке, у вас сейчас все в основном. Если сделать так то анимация глючить не будет, только учтите что вы с потока не сможете менять ваши вьюшки textView.setText("Устройство подключено"); так что нужно использовать что-то либо AsyncTask (хорошо что с коробки идет) или RxJava, хорошая библиотека которой удобно организовать многопоточность.
Пример кода с AT

```
class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
        tryConnectToWatch();
        // только уберите с этого метода все обращения к вьюшкам и возможно всех тостов
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         // конец выполнения, здесь вы уже можете поставить результаты 
         // во вьюшки так как этот метод в отличии от doInBackground() работает на main thread
    }
}
```